# Getting org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not found Issue in AEM

Tags: java, web-services, osgi, cxf, aem

I am working on an AEM maven project where I have to consume a web service. I am using Eclipse for writing code and for its implementation using CXF library. The code works fine in a sample project but as soon as I deploy package on CRXD in AEM and then try from it, it gives following error on the very first line while creating service object.

> javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$ConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

It is the code I am using.

```
        ServiceXML serviceXml = new ServiceXML(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
        IServiceXML ixmlPort = serviceXml.getSAApiTPSIntegrationsXML();
        
        ((BindingProvider) ixmlPort).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username");
        ((BindingProvider) ixmlPort).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "pssw0rd");
        
        final String username = "username";
        final String password = "pssw0rd";
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(
                            username,
                            password.toCharArray());
                    }
        });         

                
       metaData = ixmlPort.getMetadata("username", "CA");
```

These are the decencies I have included in my pom

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
        <artifactId>wssx-impl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I think probably it is unable to find this CXF library in AEM environment. I search a lot for its solution and only thing could found that in some scenarios people suggesting to use OSGI bundles for it. But I am wondering why would we need bundle when we have included dependenc ies in pom and these should be part of the package,

Comment: Nobody out there to help :(

Comment: I remember to have a lot of trouble when using cxf in AEM, I also had to use the following dependency:

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>